# opengl 1D texture: fill with arbitrary float values

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, texture-mapping, lighting

So, I'm struggling with 1D textures. What I'm trying to achieve is passing 3 float values to a fragment shader as a `uniform`. They represent a light's color, in an attempt to reuse the same shader for `n` lights, with all their info -color and position- stored in the texture. For now, I'm trying to pass only the color for a single light to test things out. So in the fragment shader I have this:

```
uniform sampler1D lightColor;
...
vec3 lc = vec3(texelFetch(lightColor, 0, 0)); // all zeroes
vec3 lc = vec3(texture(lightColor, 0, 0));    // same
```

I've tried to achieve it both with `texelFetch` and `texture` calls within the shader (either one or the other), in both cases to no avail. Please note that if I hardcode the value in the shader like this:

```
vec3 lc = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.8f);
```

then I get the expected results (which are non-zero values in `lc`), so I'm positive that, at least in the shader, the problem may be in either the `texelFetch` or `texture` calls.

Back in C++ land, the code (executed once when my `lightManager` initializes) is as follows:

```
GLfloat lightValues[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f };
GLuint lightID; // member, not a local variable.
glGenTextures(1, &lightID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, lightID);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + lightID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexStorage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 1, GL_RGB32F, 1);
glTexSubImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, 0, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, lightValues);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader->program, "light"), lightID);
```

Nothing extremely fancy going here (although definitely wrong). After going through table 6.2 of the OpenGL doc, for `glTexStorage1D` I chose 1 for `levels` (no MipMaps) and `GL_RGB32F` for `internalFormat` (since I'm trying to pass 3 floats). `width` is 1, since there is a single value. That should take care of the allocation.

Now, on to filling the buffers up with `glTexSubImage1D`, for which I choose `level` 0 (again, no MipMaps), 0 for `xoffset`, for width thrice the size of a `GLfloat`, `GL_RGB` as the format and `GLfloat` as the `type`. Finally, the actual data.

A few things about the c++ code: I correctly set the filters to `GL_NEAREST` (so that's not to blame) and I would say the uniform location/connection to the sader is correct (via `glUniform1i` and `glGetUniformLocation`).

So here come my questions:

- First and obvious, does this make sense, passing lights info via a texture? Shaders are blatantly unable to do stuff like `lights[n]`, since `n` needs to be known at compile time, so textures came naturally to mind as a way to trick this.
- Second, is my assumption correct that the size of the data may be the culprit? I've read about completeness in textures, but to be honest, it was rather brief. A size of 1 texel smells definitely fishy, though.
- Third, do you see anything else wrong? Particularly with the `internalFormat`, `format` and `type`?
- Fourth, any ideas in general why `lc` keeps being populated with zeroes?

Thanks!!

EDIT: I do not want to use techniques like multiple passing, or defining a hard limit on the number of lights passed to the shader (making `n` constant). I read too about some feature in OpenGL 4.2, I believe, which does not interest me either. I'm just trying to learn with the tools at hand (but it's 100% guaranteed in the future I will come back with questions about those topics, once I figure this out (: )

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured it out together with https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774414/raistmaj

Turns out `width` is both in `glTexStorage` and `glTexSubImage` the number of elements in the array, so 1, regardless of the number of components.

Also, `glActiveTexture` must be called before `glBindTexture` (duh!!)

Comment: You're also misusing glActiveTexture with the texture ID. OpenGL will generate an error and ignore that call.

Comment: What do you mean by misusing? Because of the sum? AFAIK that's a pretty standard way, how would you know which texture unit to activate otherwise, if `lightID` value is unknown till runtime?

Comment: What you do wrong there is adding the *texture name* to GL_TEXTURE_0. *That's not how it goes!* There's a certain number of texture units (0 to N, N being a figure you can query with `glGetInteger(            GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)` and it's valid to call `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE_0 + i)' where i is in the range 0 to N. What you generate with `glGenTextures` and bind with `glBindTexture` is a so called *texture name* and everything in the range 1 to 2^32-1 may be used as a texture name.

Comment: Regarding your question "how to know which texture unit to activate": It's up to your discretion. Think of texture units like hose fed paint guns. An OpenGL implementation gives you a certain number of paint guns, which you have to work with. But you can put a (nearly) unlimited number of dye canisters into your shop, which you can freely connect with your limited number of paint guns. `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE_0 + paint_gun_number)` selects the paint gun `glBindTexture(…, name_of_dye)` connects the hose. And `glUniform(sampler_location, paint_gun_number)` assigns paint guns to the shader.

Comment: A great explanation and analogy, danke vielmals. I see now how I was mixing things up. I find myself wondering smth related, which I post in the next comment due to size limitations.

Comment: Say I connect `M` paintguns, +1 for my lighting calculations. That value `m` changes from surface to surface, and will have a maximum of `N - 1`, correct? In other words, for drawing a complete model (composed of many surfaces), the restriction on the number of available textures is applied individually to each surface, not the model as a whole. Even more - rendering my scene completely could very well require a number of paint guns beyond `N`, as long as each of the individual surfaces does not require more than `N` paint guns. Is anything I said not true, or I understood this correctly?

Comment: Replace "surface" with "drawing batches" and you're spot on. In the old-and-busted legacy API a glBegin/glEnd block would denote a "drawing batch". These days you can recognize a cohesive drawing batch as calls to functions named `glDraw…`. Between these calls you can change the texture binding for each texture unit. – There's also an extension (and this not yet a standard feature so don't rely on it) that allows to use an arbitrary number of textures within a drawing batch, without having to bind them; that extension is called "bindless textures". I just want to pique your interest there…

Comment: I read in passing about these bindless textures. Very enlightening (pun intended) question this has been. Thank you very much.